# Criteria search

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I ran into some problems while trying to count items.

Imagine the following domain classes

```
class Book {
  String name
}
class Author {
  String name
  static hasMany = [books:Book]
}
```

**How do I get a list of Authors sorted by number of Books?**

here's my try:

```
def c = Author.createCriteris()
c.list {
  projections {
    count 'books', 'numBooks'
    groupProperty 'id'
  }
  order 'numBooks', 'desc'
}
```

but somehow I get only unusable results... and I don't know how to join the Author objects to the rsult list.... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got something!

I still don't know how to do it with a criteria, but by switching to HQL, I succeeded.

So if someone comes up with a criteria solution, he will still get the bonus for the correct answer :-)

here is my query:

```
Author.executeQuery("""
    select 
        a, size(a.books) as numBooks 
    from 
        Author a 
    group by 
        id 
    order by 
        numBooks DESC
""",[max:20])
```

This query isn't efficient, since it fetches all Authors in a loop, but that's ok for now.

Answer (score 2):

Havent tried it, but couldn't you do something like:

```
class Author {

    String name
    static hasMany = [books:Book]

    static namedQueries = {
        sortByMostBooks {
            books {
                order('size', 'desc')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then get access by the cleaner named query

```
Author.sortByMostBooks.list();
```

In addition, you may want to include a belongsTo in you Book domain class:

```
static belongsTo = Author;
```

or:

```
static belongsTo = [authors:Author];
```

if a book is likely to have multiple authors

Comment: Thanx. A named query is a great idea, but it still uses the criteria builder. And 'size' seems not to be the right syntax...